# Django LoginView print user input

Tags: django, python-3.x

**I want to print login that user input in login_form.**

I read in documentation [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views) that LoginView contains field **form**. And tried to fetch data from this field. Also tried fetch login from **request**, but it contains only AnonymousUser

**views.py**

```
class BBLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'vacancy_list/login.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("SSSS", self.form)
        log_to_file("{};{};LOGIN;\n".format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), request.user))
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends 'vacancy_list/base.html' %}

{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container"  style="margin-top:10px">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <p>You are already registered</p>
        {% else %}
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% bootstrap_form form layout='horizontal' %}
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
            {% buttons submit="Submit" %} {% endbuttons %}
        </form>
       {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`get_form()`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.contrib.auth.views/LoginView/#get_form) method of the `LoginView` if you want the form, and you are getting `AnonymousUser` because you haven't authenticated the user yet. I suggest you override the [`form_valid`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.contrib.auth.views/LoginView/#form_valid) method of the LoginView:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login


class BBLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'vacancy_list/login.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """Security check complete. Log the user in."""
        auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())

        print("SSSS", form)
        log_to_file("{};{};LOGIN;\n".format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), request.user))

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```